# how to deploy the kedro project and run the project in a new environment after kedro package command?

Tags: kedro

I have used already built pipeline using iris data and created a wheel and egg file using "kedro package". After this I created a virtual environment using python and installed both wheel and egg files there. I tried to run the pipeline file from the scripts folder in environment and (exe file too) but its throwing **"could not find kedro.yml error"**.

Can you please help if this is the right way to transfer the project and run the pipeline and if not, can you help me with the right way to deploy pipelines and run them in the new environment?

[image: error image]

Comment: I think this functionality has been broken for quite a while. In the meantime, I think your best bet is either using kedro-docker to run your pipeline with Docker https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro-docker or clone your kedro project into a new environment and run it with `kedro run`

Comment: This might help you actually: https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/issues/370

Answer (score 0):

This is covered by this issue [kedro/issues/370](https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/issues/370).  I was able to fully package a  kedro project by moving `/conf` and `.kedro.yml` into the package, and adding them to the Manifest.in.

```
# MANIFEST.in
include **/*.kedro.yml
recursive-include <project-name>/conf/ *.yml *.yaml
```